# "linearLayout cannot be resolved or it is not a field" with AdMob instructions by Google for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, android-linearlayout, processing

I am trying to find a solution to my problem by an hour and I found some topics with my similar problem, but I don't understand how to resolve.

I was developing an app with Processing for Android and I wanted to try AdMob (just for learning, for now), so I followed instructions all over the net and now I am stuck.

To add ads in the app, I was following Google instructions to add the SDK of Play Service and to add banners, but I am stuck here:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initPdService();

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pu....83399");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        // .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        // .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
                .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
```

The problem is that it give me "linearLayout cannot be resolved or it is not a field", and I don't know how to resolve. I think that the problem is in `findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)`, since the error is at "linearLayout" and not "LinearLayout".

I am sure that a lot of people find this problem, so I think that is a common problem. I already added `import android.widget.LinearLayout;`at the top of the sketch, so I don't know what is the problem.

Other infos: it is targeting Android SDK 19, as I know that Play Services want at least API level 13.

EDIT:
Here is my [old] activity_main.xml found is /res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2:
This is my new activity_main.xml, with linearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

which you have commented out. Do you have an xml file "activity_main.xml" that contains the LinearLayout with an id, linearLayout?

If yout don't have a LinearLayout with the id linearLayout, you need to add one.  Otherwise, it's trying to find a view (by id!) that doesn't exist.  For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
...
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I uncomment that line, the error is still there.
I edited the post by adding the activity_main.xml and there is no id for linearLayout

Comment: That's your issue then!  You need an id linearLayout, in order to *find* the id, linearLayout. :)

Comment: Thanks, how can I do this?
Sorry I am new to Android Development and I am doing my first app with Processing for Android eheheh

Comment: Added--see if that helps any.

Comment: Great! It worked thanks :D
Now I have another problem... I only have a white screen (with the ad banner) :\

Comment: Right!  Now you need to put stuff in the linear layout (where the '...' is).  Because this example sets the height to wrap content, and there is no content yet, the height is 0.  Try putting Space and View inside the Linear Layout.

Comment: Nothing. White screen (and the ad disappear).
It's strange, because now if I try to recompile the app with the old activity_main.xml but adding linearLayout it crashed, but the first time it started with a blank screen and the ad at the top :|

Comment: Yes, I added it in the first post

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using Processing as a library on top of the Android SDK, and it doesn't have access to the layout files, as in Processing you create your screens programatically - it is similar to one big [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class for those that are familiar with Android and not Processing.

What the actual compilation error is saying is that the generated **R.java** file is not finding the compressed resources

I've never tried to add AdMob, but really i think your issue here is that you need to instantiate a LinearLayout programatically, not via XML - as again, you won't have access to that through the PDE.

EDIT:

- just noticed that you are using Eclipse (and **LibPd** !!)... ok, so you can reach a layout
- Can you show the code where you are importing Processing into the Activity ?

Comment: Infact, now I have a white screen with the ad banner at the top...

To import Processing I copied processing-core.jar in library folder of the project, then I just extend PApplet...

`public class MainActivity extends PApplet {

 public int sketchWidth() {
  return displayWidth;
 }

 public int sketchHeight() {
  return displayHeight;
 }

 public String sketchRenderer() {
  return OPENGL;
 }

public void setup() {
// stuffs
}

public void draw() {
//stuffs
}
}`